# floating constants in C

Tags: java, c, casting, types

I have a question concerning floating constants in C.

In Java, the default type of floating point constants in double, so the following will causes a compilation error in java:

```
float f = 100.0;   // we either need to uses type case operator or put f at the end of the number constant.
```

This is because the default floating-point constants are of type double and casting from double to float without type cast operator is an error, so we need either add a type case operator or put f at the end of the number.

**So, Why in C this doesn't produce an error, Is it because the default floating-point constants are of type float, or because the compiler do an implicit down-cast conversion (that doesn't requires type case operator in C)????**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, floating point constants have type `double` by default, but a `double` can be implicitly converted to a `float` (note that you do have to be careful:  if the value of the constant is outside the range representable by a `float`, the result of such a conversion is undefined).

If you want a floating point constant of type `float`, you can append the suffix `f` to the end of the constant.

Answer (score 4):

Unsuffixed floating-point constants are double in C too.  See §6.4.4.2 of [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

You are right that it narrows here:

§6:3.1.5:

> "When a double is demoted to float, a
>   long double is demoted to double or
>   float, or a value being represented in
>   greater precision and range than
>   required by its semantic type (see
>   6.3.1.8) is explicitly converted to its semantic type, if the value being
>   converted can be represented exactly
>   in the new type, it is unchanged. If
>   the value being converted is in the
>   range of values that can be
>   represented but cannot be represented
>   exactly, the result is either the
>   nearest higher or nearest lower
>   representable value, chosen in an
>   implementation-deﬁned manner. If the
>   value being converted is outside the
>   range of values that can be
>   represented, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned."

§6:5.16:

> "The type of an assignment expression
>   is the type of the left operand [...]"

§6:5.16.1:

> "In simple assignment (=), the value
>   of the right operand is converted to
>   the type of the assignment expression
>   and replaces the value stored in the
>   object designated by the left
>   operand."

Answer (score 2):

C silently downcasts *double* to *float*.  And, as already pointed out, a floating point literal is assumed to be a double.

In *[gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)*, the compiler option **-Wconversion** (not implied in *-Wall*) gives a warning for this downcasting (for example in a literal assigment, as in your question).

> warning: conversion to 'float' from
>   'double' may alter its value